# ant reading key value property files

Tags: file, ant, properties-file

I have a property file(user.properties) like this:

```
ip=10.161.16.755
names={"10.161.16.75":"v1"}
adminPassword=admin
sshUserName=r
sshPassword=v
vc.username=administrator@address.local
```

I want to read `vc.username` and `names` into some variables and use them later in ant.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ant/9181/ant-properties#t=20170301194549270071

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your properties file in your `build xml`

```
<property file="user.properties"/>
```

And now you can use all keys defined in your properties files like a variable. For example :

`${vc.username}` will give you `administrator@address.local`

Hope this helps